# Testing API call, which calls another URL

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, guzzle

I am writing a few tests for an OAuth service.

1. I send a GET request to my `Server#1` (My own server).
2. `Server#1` sends a request to `Server#2` (Not my own), to retrieve the access token.

My issue is that I cannot create valid data for `Server#2`, to get a valid response for the request.

How can I mock the response for `Server#2` without mocking response for `Server#1` ?

Comment: Give us more details like: input data, expected results, errors/warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the mocked class to the specific class and expect the right results.

```
class Service1{

   public function __constructor(Service2 $service2){
        $this->service2 = $service2;
   }

   public function generateToken(){

     $token = $this->service2->getToken();
     return $token;
   } 
}
```

```
$mockedService2 = Mockery::mock(Service2::class);
$mockedService2->shouldReceive('getToken')->andreturn('AccessToken');
$service1 = new Service1($mockedService2);
$service1->generateToken();
```